# tcpdump based datalogger

Tags: debian, tcp, tcpdump

I am building a datalogger with raspberry pi. I have used a Shell script in rc.local, I am capturing the bytes using tcpdump. The Problem am facing is that the log file is getting replaced each and every time the pi boots on. Is there a way possible to save the log files with different names every time the pi starts.

my intial code in rc.local

```
tcpdump udp -c 600 -w new-$(date +%F-%H-%M-%S).pcap  //this writes all the 600 UDP Frames of Ethernet to the file new(time displayed in PI).pcap
```

I have tried appending the data but I want to save the log file each and every time the pi boots. With no RTC the data is a little bit incorrigible. I would like to save the file in a different names each time the PI boots. Is it possible to do that.

Comment: yup its a typo. The Directory will be root as 

    rc.local

is itself a root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it OK to have numbered logfiles instead? You could create a text file with log number, say, `lognum` and a small script to start logging:

```
#!/bin/bash
lognum=$(cat lognum)
tcpdump udp -c 600 -w log-$lognum.pcap
echo $(( $lognum + 1 )) > lognum
```

This way your logs will be numbered, and the number of the next log will be stored in `lognum`. I suggest putting `1000` as an initial value there, so that alphabetical sorting orders your logs orrectly.

Comment: That is one of the days I came back here to add to the previous answer actually, and quite a good one too. What I can add, is that once you have got the time set, you can move the files. In unix, as long the file is not closed, you can pretty rename or even delete it without ill side effects.

Comment: @dmitry Could you pls explain the first line. What does a $ Symbol indicate, I understood ýour are concatenating the log files but didn't understand it clearly. How do you suggest initalising the value 1000 to `lognum`
With the current program my logfiles are numbered appropriately. Thanks a ton for your reply :)

Comment: `$(cat lognum)` is a [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst), it means "execute the command inside `$()` and use the output in the assignement". In this case, the variable `lognum` simply gets its value from a file named `lognum` in the current directory. Initializing `lognum` simply means writing the text string `1000` to the `lognum` file.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev ya I understood how it worked. like you said it creates `lognum` file in the current Directory and each time it reboots, number is taken from the `lognum` file stored in the directory. For initilaisation, this is what you have mentioned `echo 1000 >> lognum`
this will create log-1000.pcap as the first file and it keeps on going!!

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1) Having Internet Connectivity

By the time rc.local is ran, you should have already the network interfaces up. Better install the ntpd daemon to keep up the time.

Do a

```
sudo install ntp
```

Next time you reboot it will make the time right before running tcpdump.

2) Buying a RTC time clock in alibaba/aliexpress. It is fairly cheap and easy to use.

http://www.aliexpress.com/item/DIY-DS3231-Precision-RTC-Clock-Memory-Module-for-Arduino-Raspberry-Pi/32436430982.html

3) Using mktemp for the shell to generate a random name, that will be changed after rotating the file.

Comment: how does a NTP Server works. 

What does the command 

     'ntpdate -b your_ntp_server' 

do??

Comment: I see your problem...will change the answer. Do you have internet connectivity in that machine?

Comment: When am testing the Raspberry PI as such. There is no Internet Connection. I have done some study about ntp before and I got to know that through Internet it gets time from internal clock Servers.

I feel the solution to the problem lies in how I Change the file Name each time PI boots.

Comment: How will mktemp will generate a name on it's own after each boot. I will have a look in to it. But is there a flag which changes the file name each time PI is rebooted!!

Comment: sudo apt-get install coreutils ; now run mktemp in the command line a couple of times.

Comment: this should be done in 'rc.local' or separately. I mean running the mktemp command. coreutils is completely new to me. I will look in to it and then I will try it out. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I am talking about running it in the command like for testing. to use in a script, you do A=\`mktemp\` and then tcpdump .... -w $A.pcap

Comment: (open the URL and see the price of the RTC clock too)

Comment: the mktemp is based on time, and eventually can produce similar names. the answer from Dmitry is a better ideia for filename generation.